# Crystal Reports: price for latest transaction

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to create a field to put on group footer #1 that shows the latest price by customer type. The grouping is item_ID (see below). So for example if there were transactions over time with varying prices to Factories and to Retail stores, it would only show the price for the last time that item was sold for a factory(I have a separate field for retail stores). I have tried a few things but nothing is working. For example:

On the detail level:
if {TRANSACTIONS.TRANDATE} = Maximum ({@FactoryTranDate}, {TRANSACTION_LINES.ITEM_ID}) then
{TRANSACTIONS_LINES.PRICE}

FactoryTranDate is basically: if customer type = factory then trandate. Then I created a max of this on group footer #1.

This appears correctly on the transaction line but if the last transaction for that item wasn't to a factory, it will be 0 on the summary line. I tried to do a Max of that detail level field but it doesn't come up for my summary fields, I am assuming cause it gets confused upon doing a summary of a summary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the problem you are running into is the column of data you are trying to print in the footer has multiple rows and you can't predict where the value you want might be within those rows.  So by the time you get to the footer, it only has the value held by the last row that printed.

To get around this you would want to use a few formula fields to create variables that can be used to store the value you want from the correct row when it is printed.

I would plan to use 3 formula fields.  One to initialize your variable and set it to a default value of zero.  Place this formula field in the header that corresponds to your footer and this will ensure the variable exists and is reset to a default value for each grouped value in this header.  The formula will look something like this:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar price:=0.00;
```

The second formula will declare the same variable again, and it will also include some logic to know when to set the value of the variable.  This formula field should be placed within the section that prints the detail records for the grouping.  The formula would look something like this:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
If <condition to evaluate> Then
     Shared NumberVar price:={TRANSACTIONS_LINES.PRICE}
```

I'm not entirely sure what condition you will want to evaluate here though based on the information you've provided, but I suspect it will be along the lines of `if customer type = factory`.  However, it should be a condition that is only true when you want to capture the price of the detail record within the grouping.  If you have multiple cases where it might be true, then you will want to sort them in such a way that the one you wish to capture is printed last within the group.  Since you stated that it should be the last factory price, then I would sort by Transaction Date and the variable will change its value with each record that has a true condition and will only keep the price from the one with the latest Transaction Date.

The third formula field is simply for printing the value of your variable in the footer.  This field will be placed in the footer section and will display the value of the variable on your report.  The formula for this field will look something like this:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar price;
```

The formula fields used in the header and details sections can be suppressed if you don't want them to print on your report, but I would recommend waiting until you have the final value printed in the footer verified before suppressing them.  This will allow you to see how the value of your variable changes as the report is generated if you are not familiar already with using variable in this manner.  You may also want to read up on the scope of variables in crystal reports if this is a new topic for you.  My suggestions here all use the SHARED scope, but there are also LOCAL and GLOBAL scopes.  GLOBAL might work better in your case, but I tend to favor SHARED in examples such as these because they have the most broad scope.  LOCAL definitely will not work for you here though.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for the detailed answer and the suggestions for further things to look into!